# Address to fish_config run in headless virtualbox vm to access from host OS?

Tags: fish

I wish to customize fish shell via browser config, the problem is that its installed on headless virtualbox vm with which I work via ssh connection. After running from terminal `fish_config` just prints that browser not found on system (of course) and no address. So my question is what address that is, so I can access it from host OS, and if its doable at all.

Answer (score 1):

Currently `fish_config` only accepts connections from localhost, for security reasons. [Issue 1916](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1916) tracks adding an option to allow non-local connections. You might also be able to get ssh port forwarding to work.